# Python Scrapy extract child

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following situation:

```
<div class="question"> 
    <div class="post-layout">
        <div class="post-text">
            <p> Sample Question </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="answer"> 
    <div class="post-layout">
        <div class="post-text">
            <p> Sample Answer </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract the text of the `question` class separately from the `answer` class.

I tried: `response.css('.post-text > p::text').extract()` but this extracts the question and answer together.

I tried: `response.css('.question > .post-text > p::text').extract()` but it doesn't return anything.

I also tried: `response.xpath(".//div[@class='question']/div[@class='post-text']/p//text()").extract()` but it doesn't return anything.

I am new to Scrapy so maybe I am doing something wrong... any help will be appreciated!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. The `>` in your selector asks for a child of what you are selecting. As the `<p>` isn't a direct child of `<div class="answer">` it doesn't find it. You can fix this by just removing it

```
question = response.css(".question p::text").get()
answer = response.css(".answer p::text").get()
```

Note I use `get()` instead of `extract()` just because this is the [recommended way to do this now.](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#extract-and-extract-first)

Your second attempt doesn't work because you are missing the `post-layout` class. The correct way to use that approach would be e.g.

```
response.css('.question > .post-layout > .post-text > p::text')
```

The `xpath` equivalents are

```
question = response.xpath('//div[@class="question"]//p/text()').get()
answer = response.xpath('//div[@class="answer"]//p/text()').get()
```